# Function not working in postgresql 13

Tags: postgresql, functions

We have below function which needs to check some conditions before accepting the password from user input.

Here we are first accepting the user input through function call.

1. First it will check complexity of password. once the password is accepted it will insert into pwdhistory table.
2. if more than 3 entries is exist in pwdhistory table, then it should delete very first entry  and store new altered password.that means it should store only 3 password for each user.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION public.usp_loginaudit(usename varchar,password text)
 RETURNS void AS 
 $function$

DECLARE
   min_password_length int := 8;  
   
begin

--here we will check password length 

  IF length($2) >= min_password_length THEN
EXECUTE 'ALTER USER ' || $1 || ' WITH PASSWORD '''|| $2||'''' ;
     ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Password too short!'
      USING ERRCODE = '22023' ,
      DETAIL = 'Please check your password.' ,
      HINT = 'Password must be at least ' || min_password_length || ' characters.';
    END IF;
        
---once above successfully executed then it will insert in pwdhistory table.

INSERT INTO pwdhistory (usename,password,changed_on) values($1,md5($2),now());
      EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN     
      RAISE '23505'
      USING DETAIL = 'Password already used earlier.',
      HINT = 'Please try again with a different password.';

 

DECLARE   
r_count integer := (SELECT count(1) from pwdhistory p where p.usename = $1);

 
----here we will remove very first entry from pwdhistory that means we want to keep only 3 entries for each user.

--- Now the issue is, once we call the function below code is not executing. something is wrong with first exception which is raised for check min_password_length . 

begin
if (r_count > 3)
Then  
 create temp table tempwd 
        ( 
        pwd_date timestamp with time zone null
        );
        insert into tempwd
        select p.changed_on 
        from pwdhistory p where p.usename = $1 order by p.changed_on desc limit 3;
    
        delete from pwdhistory p where p.usename = $1 and p.changed_on not in (select pwd_date from tempwd);
                                                                                
        drop table tempwd; 
        
end if ;
end;
end;

 
$function$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I mean to say very new entry is not deleting from pwdhistory  table. also not getting any error to past here.

Comment: Why are you creating the temporary table? Why not just put the logic that fills it into the where clause of the delete statement?